# How to drag fill series in excel to adjust sequencing without removing the hyperlinks attached to cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, bookmarks

I have a range of cells in a column in excel, that have some number in them along with text. For Example:

```
TA_47
TA_48
TA_49
TA_50
TA_51
TA_52
TA_53
TA_54
TA_55
TA_56
TA_57
TA_58
TA_59
TA_60
```

Now I apply bookmarks to some cells on other sheets, and delete one or two rows, such that the numbering gets disturbed. Then, i drag and fill the series and find that the bookmark information with the selected cells gets vanished. Is there any way to avoid this? Such that numbering can be adjusted and the bookmarks can be retained as they were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want what you are describing, you need to enter a formula in the cells instead of a value. You can use the rownumber as a counter. In your example, starting at cell A1, enter: `="TA_" & ROW(A1)` and copy-paste down.